# Testing office-js addins against old versions of excel

Tags: excel, testing, office365, office-js

I'm developing an office-js addin for corporate client which insists on using legacy versions of Excel (1708 or 1808).

But when I install excel from office 365, I get version 1906.

In the old days, with software, there were installers you could find in a directory that had version stamps on them, and you could create a VM, and just install the version you wanted. But the fancier installers appear to download stuff automatically and always (at least default to) the latest versions.

How do I install a legacy version of Excel on a VM for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no special process for getting an earlier version when you are testing add-ins. It should be the same process as an end user would use. Please try the steps at this article: [Revert to an earlier version of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2770432/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2013-or-office-2016-clic). I think you can find the build numbers that you will need either from your customer or from this page: [Update history of Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office365-proplus-by-date?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fae942449-1fca-4484-898b-a933ea23def7).